# managing web pages and URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i have a site tree like this

1. `controller` (folder)

   > file1.php
   > file2.php
   > .....
   > file10.php
2. `view` (folder)

   > home.php
   > profile.php
   > message.php
   > login.php
   > register.php
   > .....
3. `index.php`
4. `css.css`
5. `js.js`

---

At present `index.php` is common and it includes the page that user wants like this
`www.mysite.com/?show=profile`
first i am verifying the variable `show` and include the corresponding page on my `index.php`

**index.php**

```
$show=$_GET['show'].".php";
include("view/".$show);
```

but i dont want my URL like this `www.mysite.com/?show=profile` instead i want that if a user `john` clicked for page `profile` then my URL should be

```
www.mysite.com/john/profile/
```

as i know it says : go to folder `john` then `profile` and at last `index.php`

does i have to make every folders and files for each user or is there any way that i can accomplish it using the present Site Tree ??

I hope u understood what i trying to say :(

Thanx

Comment: @Quentin happy to see you again here :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a .htaccess file to create pretty urls: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Edit: Mine looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf)$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?params=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: oh yes, i heard about that :D but i dont know how to use it, thanx i will read ur tutorial :)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: I added my own htaccess(hope it helps). Sorry :-p